# javascript: convert string to ISO-compatible date

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have a list of dates like so

```
august 2015
september 2015
october 2015
november 2015
december 2015
```

that I want to convert to ISO format for storage

```
2015-08-01T00:00:00-07:00
2015-09-01T00:00:00-07:00
2015-10-01T00:00:00-07:00
2015-11-01T00:00:00-07:00
2015-12-01T00:00:00-08:00
```

Typically, I use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for something like this, but it looks like they are soon going to [stop supporting this functionality](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407).

How do I write something that replaces it? Thus far, I've been using moment because I didn't want to have to worry about things like Daylight Savings adjustments, etc.

Comment: As explained, I wanted to make sure that I didn't whiff on things like Daylight Savings time. Looks like Moment handles my use case after all.

Comment: Moment is probably doing exactly what I suggested. The JS `Date` object handles DST itself.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful and answers my question without attacking me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like moment does handle this, fairly trivially; you just need to add a [format for parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

```
monthMoment = moment("august 2015", "MMMM YYYY");
```

Comment: yes, and then you call `.format()` to get the string in the form you requested.